# How to get Lat & Long Value for an address input in android?

Tags: android

I have gone through many post but did not got any clear answer. I want to get address input from user and want to get lat long value corresponding to that address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HLMGTFY: What you're trying to do is called Geocoding, and here are the API notes from Android on it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html. Note that you will need to have a valid Google Maps API key first.

Comment: Is there any sample application where i can have a look how to use the classes

Comment: Another Google search for "Android Geocoding Example" gave me this: http://www.anddev.org/simple_googlemaps_geocoder_-_convert_address_to_lon-lat-t2936.html

Comment: Hi Brian, I have gone through that code, but when i m running it, it always closes the app. there is some error in it

Comment: Are you running on a device or in the emulator? Also, did you read through the comments on that post? They might help you to resolve the error you're getting. Last but not least, have you tried debugging to find the problem LOC for yourself?

Comment: i am running on emulator. Dont have a real device

Comment: Well, your emulator doesn't have GPS, so that is likely part of the problem. Did you read the comments on the post? It looks like there were other users getting errors as well, but were able to resolve them. Also, have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have access to the internet, you can use [Google's geocoding api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

It'll give you a normal request that will return Json or XML containing everything you'd want about the address.